React Native, Sending Image From Axios but not receiving at Multer Express JS
I am not able to receive image sent from axios/react native at express js server. It works fine when i sent the same request to server from Postman/ThunderClient.
Here is a code which i have used in react native.
const pickImage = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });

    if (!result.canceled) {
      setImage(result.assets[0]);
    }
  };

  const createFormData = async (body: any = {}) => {
    const data = new FormData();

    if (image) {
      const response = await fetch(image.uri || "");
      const blob = await response.blob();

      data.append("image", blob, "profile.jpg");
    }

    Object.keys(body).forEach((key) => {
      data.append(key, body[key]);
    });

    console.log(blob);

    return data;
  };

  const uploadImage = async (id: string, access_token: string) => {
    const body = await createFormData({ id });
    const response = await axios.post(
      `${API_BASE_URL}user/validate/upload-profile-image`,
      body,
      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
        },
        transformRequest: [(data) => body],
        validateStatus: function (status) {
          return status < 500;
        },
      }
    );

    return response;
  };

Here is what i am getting on console logging blob - {"_parts": [["image", [Blob]], ["id", "af1ee491-61c9-4368-93ef-813256b041dc"]]}
I have tried everything on it, doesn't seem to be working anything. Any suggestions appreciated.
Thanks.

Share a successful Postman request.

I solved this problem by switch to expo file system - FileSystem.uploadAsync method for sending request instead of using axios and fetch.

Using UploadAsync Method of expo file system solves this problem.
const options: FileSystem.FileSystemUploadOptions = {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    Accept: "image/jpeg, image/png",
  },
  httpMethod: "POST",
  uploadType: FileSystem.FileSystemUploadType.MULTIPART,
  fieldName: "image",
  parameters: {
    id,
  },
};

const response = await FileSystem.uploadAsync(
  `${API_BASE_URL}user/validate/upload-profile-image`,
  image?.uri || "",
  options
);

